# Oracle SQL query to fetch the values with the help of "Case When" Clause

Tags: oracle, select, oracle11g, case, sql-view

I am trying to execute the oracle sql query to fetch some values with the help of "CASE WHEN THEN" clause, but the shows some error with error says :

ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 13 Column: 5

Comment: What you are trying you do. After `then` clause there should not be any select statement. There should be only scalar values.

Comment: @Exhausted, Thank you for your comment. Ok, then what type of query i should write for this time of conditions ?

Comment: @Exhausted, Condition like
    if () {
    selecting value with some conditions
    } else {
    selecting value with some other condition
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is similiar to:

```
with d1 as (select 1 col1, 'A' col2 from dual union select 2, 'B' from dual),
d2 as (select 1 col1, 'Q' col2, 'W' col3, 'E' col4 from dual),
d3 as (select 2 col1, 'R' col2, 'T' col3, 'Y' col4 from dual)
select d1.col1, d1.col2, 
    case d1.col2 
    when 'A' then 
      (select d2.col2, d2.col3, d2.col4 from d2 where d2.col1 = d1.col1)
    else 
      (select d3.col2, d4.col3, d5.col4 from d2 where d2.col1 = d1.col1)
    end
  from d1
```

and you get ORA-00913: too many values

What you should do is probably something like:

```
with d1 as (select 1 col1, 'A' col2 from dual union select 2, 'B' from dual),
d2 as (select 1 col1, 'Q' col2, 'W' col3, 'E' col4 from dual),
d3 as (select 2 col1, 'R' col2, 'T' col3, 'Y' col4 from dual)
select d1.col1, d1.col2 decision_field, 
    case d1.col2 when 'A' then d2.col2 else d3.col2 end col2,  
    case d1.col2 when 'A' then d2.col3 else d3.col3 end col3,  
    case d1.col2 when 'A' then d2.col4 else d3.col4 end col4  
  from d1
    left join d2 on d2.col1 = d1.col1
    left join d3 on d3.col1 = d1.col1
```

results:

```
col1 decision_field col2 col3 col4
1    A              Q    W    E
2    B              R    T    Y
```

Comment: Your query work well but still in my case i cant able to do it.  
I just want to have some set of conditions in another conditions like:  
  
 if (condition1 = 'y') {  
   condition2  
   condition3  
   condition4  
 } else {  
   condition5  
   condition6  
 }

Comment: I think that it can be done by reorganising `joins` or by using `union`. But you didn't clearly say what you try to achieve.
What is in table2 (I see only field FUND_ORG_SECURITY_IND mentioned in query),
What is the relation between table1 and table2. Is this really carthesian product as this appears from `from table1, table2, table3`?
Are your current inner queries (these after `then` ... and after `else` ...) working for you?
It would be good if you attached sample listing of desired output.
Without these tips I'm not able to help.